# using matches() function with rename_all() R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to use a dplyr function:

```
rename_all(paste0, "_x")
```

which adds _x to every column in the DF (by keeping its original name + _x)
It works great but I want to exclude a column from this function using
`!matches()` or something.
I'm unable to combine these two functions.

Comment: Please make the question [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rename_at`:

```
library(dplyr)
rename_at(df, vars(!contains("string_to_exclude")), list( ~paste0(., "_x")))
```